# Powershell: Using "Get-ADUser -Filter SamAccountName" as variable

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory, get-aduser

Code:

```
$kullaniciisim = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq '23214214'} | Select-Object SamAccountName
$kullaniciisim
```

Input:

```
SamAccountName
-------------- b.ozturk
```

I want `$kullaniciisim` to be `b.ozturk`  not `SamAccountName -------------- b.ozturk`

How can I do it?

Comment: `$kullaniciisim.SamAccountName` or `| Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName`

Answer (score 0):

yea did it. Here is the fix:

$cc =  $kullaniciisim.SamAccountName
$cc